# How to identify rows that are not starting with a certain pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, character, row

I have a data table with a column with different characters and I want to check if all the rows are starting with "99", "15", "16"or "17" and have between 4-5 characters.

Any idea of how to do it? I thought about using grep but it doesn't really works..!

Thanks

Aida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is called `dat` and `x` is the column of interest, the following will return all the rows that start with the desired characters and that have 4 or 5 characters:

```
dat[grepl("^(15|16|17|99)", dat$x) & nchar(dat$x) %in% 4:5, ]
```

To return rows that do not meet the criteria:

```
dat[!(grepl("^(15|16|17|99)", dat$x) & nchar(dat$x) %in% 4:5), ]
```

Here are answers to your comment:

1) To check whether all rows meet the criteria:

```
all(grepl("^(15|16|17|99)", dat$x) & nchar(dat$x) %in% 4:5)
```

2) To identify rows that do not meet the criteria:

```
which(!(grepl("^(15|16|17|99)", dat$x) & nchar(dat$x) %in% 4:5))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, your code works, the thing is that I want the rows that DOES NOT match that rules; something  that says if any row does not match `dat[grepl("^(15|16|17|99)", dat$x) & nchar(dat$x) %in% 4:5, ]` return TRUE. Or maybe with the which statement that can return me the rows that DOES NOT match that line of code.